# Using public_activity with acts_as_follower and devise, how can I show only the user's activities and those of the people he follows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get my notifications controller, which is based around the public_activity gem, to show the user's activities in addition to the activities of those he follows.

I have it working to show the activities of those the user follows, but I can't seem to get the user's own activities to be included.

In other words, this works:

```
class NotificationsController < CooperativeController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.where(:owner_id => current_user.following_users, :owner_type => 'User').order('created_at DESC')

  end
end
```

While this doesn't:

```
class NotificationsController < CooperativeController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def index
    notify_user_of = current_user.following_users
    notify_user_of << current_user

    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.where(:owner_id => notify_user_of, :owner_type => 'User').order('created_at DESC')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `notify_user_of = current_user.following_users` was not an array as I had thought, but an active record object.  By manually creating the array and adding individual users to it I was able to achieve the desired result.

```
...
notify_user_of = []
notify_user_of << current_user
for user in current_user.following_users
  notify_user_of << user
end
...
```

Comment: Thanks, Karen...Trying to puzzle out a similar problem now. I'm afraid your solution might not scale well -- I'd be curious to hear how it ends up performing. I want the @activities to include not just those of the people the user is following, but those which affect the user's objects. So I see the notification if someone, say, comments on my post, even if I am not following that person.