# Public Activity - show only activity about self created objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, android-activity, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I followed Ryan Bates Tutorial on [Public Acticvity](http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity). I'm trying to show `ONLY` notifications about objects the current_user owns.

In my Situation => `Comments`.

my `Activities Controller`

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order('created_at desc').where(owner_id: current_user.following_users, owner_type: "User")
  end
end
```

I'm using `current_user.following_users` to get all followed Users. To get activity if they Upload a Picture.

**AT THIS POINT**: Activities are shown from all followed User's, and THATS the problem.. All activities.

I want to show only activities that concern the current_user, only activities about his own objects.

**For example.**

- current_user Uploads a Picture, UserX comments on this Picture. I want the Notification.
- UserX comments on a Picture from UserY. I don't want this notification.

For now if `current_user` follows `UserX`, i'm getting all the notifications from UserX's Activities, and not only the notifications that concerns the current_user.

But i'm completely clueless on how to achieve this. Has anyone some helping hand unoccupied ?

I found a pretty similar problem, but i don't understand the Answer -> [Using public_activity with acts_as_follower and devise, how can I show only the user's activities and those of the people he follows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486118/using-public-activity-with-acts-as-follower-and-devise-how-can-i-show-only-the?rq=1)

Another one: [Rails getting activity feed that only involves current_user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505522/rails-getting-activity-feed-that-only-involves-current-user?rq=1)

Comment: What if another User Z who is not a follower but commented on current_user's photo? Do you need to show that?

Comment: Yes, sorry i made that not clear.. Editing now

Comment: Can't the "recipient" solution solve your problem as you mentioned last?

Comment: I'm looking in to it now. Because i still need to show Uploaded Pictures from followed users..

Comment: It Seems to be working with Comments. Now i need to find how to include the Pictures Activity

Comment: I could add a similar method like the 'recipient' that targets all users who follows current_user. Searching on that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the feature you asked is a bit beyond the scope of general activities, but rather like notifications.

The "recipient" solution should be able to solve this exact problem. But you may still want the owner to show this activity, as well as the current_user. If so you need to create two activities and there needs workaround not to show them all in public. So, this may work, but duplicate record and extra code.

A better logic may be to process activities after created, judge the logic, and send notification, either on request or backend(better).

*Notice: Sharmeless ad below :)*

I have similar concern before and found it hard to reuse Public Activity's activity records again for other purpose. So I made a gem [simple_activity](https://github.com/billychan/simple_activity) which is even simpler on displaying activities but open the door to reuse them again. This gem is still at very early stage so be cautious. Check it if it helps.

Comment: Can you join me on Chat? -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45403/public-activity-problems

Comment: @TheMiniJohn, sorry but very late here and I'm going to sleep. Please add comments here and I'll try to answer at my best tomorrow.

Comment: Kay, will try to chat you up tomorrow.